# Sharepoint 2013 - Add Discussion Board in PageLayout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can i add Discussion board on all pages of my sharepoint website using Page Layout?

Is it possible without using SharePoint designer?

I am trying to add the discussion board in the page layout just like we add any web part in any page by clicking on "edit" button on the right top of the page.